# Link to pictures on a NAS in local network

Tags: ftp, cifs

I am running a raspberry Pi as a virtual picture frame in my home, using photos that are located on a synology NAS on the same network. I would like to be able to generate a qr code with a link to the currently displaying picture (creating the qr code is not the issue).  I then want to be able to share the (full-res) picture from an android phone without having to install any apps, mounting shares etc. Is this possible? Do I need to run a web server on the NAS for this to work, or can I use an existing protocol / link format?

Currently people keep taking pictures of the picture frame itself, and these have started showing up on the rotation of pictures in the system... It is starting to get ridiculous and I want to provide an easy solution to sharing the pictures